# session variables in a PHP Login Script

Tags: php, database

I have just finished creating an entire login and register systsem in PHP, but my problem is I haven't used any sessions yet. I'm kind of a newbie in PHP and I've never used sessions before. What I want to do is , when i click on login button it home page should open with user name in body of that page ... but because of that session releated code in header.inc.php my main page couldn't load ..it shows like web page not found when i click on login button ..can any one tell me where is my mistake.. this first time i m asking question in stackoverflow ..so sorry for any mistake , and thanks in advance..

below all of my code works:
 1. index.php main page

```
<code>
 <!doctype html>
<?php include( "./inc/header.inc.php"); ?>

<?php
$reg=@$_POST['reg'];
//declaring variables tp prevent error
 $fn="";// first name
 $ln="";//last name
 $un="";//username
 $em="";//email
 $em2="";//email2
 $pswd="";//password
 $pswd2="";//password2
 $d="";//sign up date
 $u_check="";//check if username exist


 //registration form
 $fn=strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
 $ln=strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
 $un=strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
 $em=strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
 $em2=strip_tags(@$_POST['email2']);
 $pswd=strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
 $pswd2=strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);
 $d=date("Y-m-d");//Year-Month_Day

 if($reg){
if($em=$em2){
    //check if user already exist
$u_check = mysqli_query( $db_conx ,"SELECT username FROM user WHERE                                          `username = '$un'");`
        // count the amount of the row where username= $un
         $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
             if($check == 0){
        //check all the field have been filled in

            //check password match
            if($pswd==$pswd2){
//Encrypt Password and Password2 using Md5 before sending to database     
                        $pwsd=md5($pswd);
                        $pwsd2=md5($pswd2);
                        $query=mysqli_query( $db_conx , "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('', '$un' , '$fn', '$ln' , '$em' , '$pswd' , '$d' , '0')");
                        die("<h2>Welcome To FriendsBook</h2> Login To your Account to Get Started...");
            }
                    else{
                   echo "Your Password Don'T Match!";
                     }  
                    }
               else{
                echo "UserName Already Taken..!";
                  } 

    }
    else{
   echo "Your Email Doesn't Match!..";
   }   

}

     // User Login code

   if(null!==(@$_POST["user_login"]) && null!==(@$_POST["password_login"])){

  $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);
 $sql = mysqli_query($db_conx , "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username =     '$user_login' AND password = '$password_login_md5' LIMIT 1"); //query
 // check for existance
 $userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count The Name Of and return
   if($userCount==1){
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql , MYSQLI_NUM)){
           $id = $row["id"];
       }
          session_start();
         $_SESSION["user_login"] = $user_login;
         header("location: home.php");
         exit();
       }else{
       echo 'That Information is Incorrect , Try Again !!';
       exit();
      }
   }



 ?>

      <div style="width:800px; margin:0px auto 0px auto;">
      <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="60%" valign="top">
              <h2>Already a Member? Sign in below! </h2>
              <form action="index.php" method="POST">
                 <input type="text" name="user_login" size="25" placeholder="UserName" /><br /><br />
                 <input type="text" name="password_login" size="25" placeholder="Password" /><br /><br />
                 <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" >
              </form>





        </td>
        <td width="40%" valign="top">
            <h2>Sign Up Below</h2>
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="fname"  maxlength="25" placeholder="First Name"  title="Maximum Limit Of First Name is 25 Character" required /><br /><br />
                <input type="text" name="lname"  maxlength="25" placeholder="Last Name"  title="Maximum Limit Of Last Name is 25 Character"  required/><br /><br />
                <input type="text" name="username"  maxlength="25" placeholder="UserName"  title="Maximum Limit Of Username is 25 Character" required/><br /><br />

                <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="35" placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$"  required /><br /><br />


                <input type="email" name="email2" maxlength="35" placeholder="Re-Enter Email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" required/><br /><br />

                <input type="password" name="password" min="8" maxlength="25" placeholder="Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" 
                title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter,
                and at least 8 or more characters" required /><br /><br />

                <input type="password" name="password2" min="8" maxlength="25" placeholder="Re-Enter Password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" 
                title="Must contain at least one number and one uppercase and lowercase letter,
                and at least 8 or more characters" required/><br /><br />

                <input type="submit" name="reg" value="Sign Up!" >
             </form>
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

      <?php include( "./inc/footer.inc.php");?>`
```

2.header.inc.php code

```
    <?php include( "./inc/connect.inc.php");
 session_start();
 // Store Session Data
  if(isset($_SESSION["user_login"])){
    header("location: home.php");
   }
  else
   }


 ?>



  <html>
  <head>
  <title>FriendsBook</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="headerMenu">
         <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="logo">
               <img src="img/friendsbooklogo.PNG"/>
            </div>
            <div class="Search_box">
                 <form action="Search.php" method="GET" id="search">
                 <input type="text" name="q" size="60"    placeholder="Search..."/>
                 </form>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="menu">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About</a>
            <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            <a href="#">Sign IN</a>

         </div>
      </div>
           </body>
```

3.connect.inc.php

```
  <?php
 $db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","" , "friendsbook" );
   ?>
```

4.logout.php

```
  <?php
  session_start();
 session_destroy();
 header("Location : index.php");
?>
```

5.home.php

```
 <?php

 include( "./inc/header.inc.php"); 
 echo $_SESSION["user_login"];

 ?>
```